# How to use adduser command with options

Tags: linux

I cant find how to use the command adduser with options. Lets say that I want to add bob and change the shell to /bin/bash how would the command look like ?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use adduser? Isn't the command useradd more suitable for your requirements?

Comment: `man adduser` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the man page for the program by typing `man adduser`. In the `OPTIONS` section it reads:

```
--shell SHELL
    Use  SHELL  as  the  user's login shell, rather than the default specified by the configuration file.
```

So, your command would look like `adduser --shell /bin/bash bob`.
Additionally, you can create your user and modify its default login shell in /etc/passwd on most systems. Example:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

where

```
{user}:{password}:{user id number}:{user's group id number}:{full name of user}:{home directory}:{login shell}
```

In this case, you'd want to modify the {login shell} part.
This

```
bob:x:123:123:Bob_McBob:/home/bob:/bin/sh
```

becomes this:

```
bob:x:123:123:Bob_McBob:/home/bob:/bin/bash
```

Have a nice day! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
# useradd -m -s /bin/bash bob
# passwd bob
```

Better not add password as CLI via `useradd -p password` to avoid history reading

Check

```
useradd -h
```

Comment: One important thing is that you have to specify a password somewhere to allow the new user to log in for the first time, either with `sudo passwd bob` or by adding the `-p` flag to `useradd`. Otherwise, `/etc/shadow` will have a `!!` in place of the password field for that user, making the account effectively disabled until `passwd` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using `RHEL` which has a slighlty different syntax of it, you should go with `useradd` like so:

```bsh
$ sudo useradd -d /home/bob -m -s /bin/bash bob 

$ sudo passwd bob
 New password: 
 Retype new password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
```

or if you don't want to bother with `sudo passwd` you can do it in one line with

```bsh
sudo useradd -d /home/bob -m -s /bin/bash -p [PASSWORD] bob
```

But you must set a password for that user to allow them to login, and then change their password later for themselves. If you don't specify a password when you create the account, the account will remain disabled in terms of login and the only way to access it will be by `su` - aka switch user - executed by another account with root privileges.